# radio button with font awesome in html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a radio button with **Font Awesome** working outside of HTML table. In the table, it just hides/shows between the two radios in the off state. I don't think I am referencing the CSS right. I am using AngularJS. I am passing in a `vehicle.isMasterLink` attribute which is a boolean field.

I am not sure if using two toggles is the correct way to handle this.

Here is my JavaScript in the controller:

```
$scope.toggleRadioButton = function(vehicle) {
    if (!vehicle.isMasterLink) {
        vehicle.isMasterLink = true;
    }
    else {
        vehicle.isMasterLink = false;
    }
};
```

Here is the HTML outside the HTML table that works:

```
<div>
    <input id="radio-1" class="radio-custom" name="radio-group" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label"></label>
</div>
```

Here is my HTML table with how I am trying to implement it. see the bottom of the table:

```
<table style="width: 100%" class="" id="toSourceTable" style="height:600px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:50px; height: 35px"></th>
            <th style="width:50px">Mstr</th>
            <th style="width:270px">Key</th>
            <th style="width:350px">Short Desc</th>
            <th style="width:100px">Mfg Code</th>
            <th style="width:10px">Options</th>
            <th style="width:10px">Links</th>
            <th style="width:10px">Status</th>
            <th style="width:100px">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="links-table-body-font">
        <tr ng-repeat="vehicle in toSourceVehicles">
            <td data-title="' '">
                <div class="multi-checkbox" ng-click="toggleLinkStatus(vehicle);">
                    <span class="fa fa-link check" style="background: #0073C0 !important;"
                          ng-if="vehicle.linkStatus == 'linked'"></span>
                    <span class="unchecked"
                          ng-if="vehicle.linkStatus == ''"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-chain-broken unchecked" style="background: #0073C0 !important;"
                          ng-if="vehicle.linkStatus == 'partial'"></span>
                    <span class="unchecked"
                          ng-if="!vehicle.linkStatus"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Mstr'">
                <div style="width: 50px">
                    <div>
                        <div ng-click="toggleRadioButton(vehicle);">
                            <input class="radio-custom fa fa-check checked" id="radio-1" name="radio-group"
                                   type="radio" ng-if="vehicle.isMasterLink ==true">
                            <label for="radio-1" class="radio-custom-label"></label>
                            <input class="radio-custom unchecked" id="radio-2"
                                   name="radio-group" type="radio" ng-if="!vehicle.isMasterLink">
                            <label for="radio-2" class="radio-custom-label"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS that works with the radio buttons outside table:

```
.radio-custom {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.radio-custom, .radio-custom-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-custom-label {
    position: relative;
}

.radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.radio-custom + .radio-custom-label:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.radio-custom:checked + .radio-custom-label:before {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #bbb;
}

.radio-custom:focus + .radio-custom-label {
    outline: 1px solid #ddd; /* focus style */
}    

.radio-custom .checked {
    content: "\f00c";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #bbb;
}
```

I am suing AngularJS to populate the data in the table. How can I get the radio button to work with the CSS? It seems like the buttons are hiding/showing correctly, just no checkmark is showing. Maybe, I am going about it wrong?

Comment: Ok first of all clean your code - remove those comments, !importants and style="" put them in css. Then put your code on plunker and show us your model in particular "toSourceVehicles". Also are you sure you don't want checkboxes instead of radio buttons - radios are linked - so you can chose only one of them. And to toggle something just use value = !value it's much cleaner and avoids having 7 lines of code for one liner. You should probably set ng-model on your input fields and then you won't have to do ng-clicks and you should use ng-class to add class to same element you don't need ng-ifs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your the problem is the **id** used in input and label tags. The label's **for** attribute is associated with an **id** of an input (these **id** must be unique for a correct funcionality).

The solution is create unique **id** for each radoibutton, you can use object id if exits or $index keyword from AngularJS. I show you an example in the following fragment of code.

```html
<td data-title="'Mstr'">
    <div style="width: 50px">
        <div>
            <div ng-click="toggleRadioButton(vehicle);">
                <input class="radio-custom fa fa-check checked" id="{{ 'radio-1-'+ $index }}" name="{{ 'radio-group' + $index }}" type="radio" ng-if="vehicle.isMasterLink ==true">
                <label for="{{ 'radio-1-'+ $index }}" class="radio-custom-label"></label>
                <input class="radio-custom unchecked" id="{{ 'radio-2-'+ $index }}" name="radio-group" type="radio" ng-if="!vehicle.isMasterLink">
                <label for="{{ 'radio-2-'+ $index }}" class="radio-custom-label"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Hope that help you.